Bitcoin Core balance differs from that shown by mempool.space
I restored a wallet.dat created with version 22.0. In Bitcoin Core 27.1, it now shows a balance of 1.16387212. My address 39L1wGdaPemy8vgQdz7CNU3QBDXthurLb7 shows a balance of 1.15278884 on mempool.space.
I noticed that there is a difference in how a transaction on 2022-03-05 was recorded. Bitcoin Core shows only a confirmed transaction spending 0.00011193 that day, but mempool.space shows the transaction differently:

It has the two inputs
39L1wGdaPemy8vgQdz7CNU3QBDXthurLb7   ‎  0,00697175 BTC
39L1wGdaPemy8vgQdz7CNU3QBDXthurLb7     ‎0,00522346 BTC 

and the two outputs
1M2zeGsuqcNya9o5UyjtfQLC1wCsKFxsPb       ‎0,00010000 BTC
bc1qfjsm7jwdf3u7udnxhjtmpjvwuu2nvyjcq27pgj  ‎0,01208328 BTC 

The total is 0.01219521.
The single address I used in Bitcoin Core at that time is the same as 39L1wGdaPemy8vgQdz7CNU3QBDXthurLb7.
Will this situation bar me from spendings of my assets? What is wrong?
How can I make my Bitcoin Core 27.1 see this transaction?

Hi Pavel, I edited your question to make it a bit easier to understand. I hope that I correctly understood what you are asking. Please edit it further or revert my changes if I got it wrong.

I think that Bitcoin Core is showing you the net effect of the transaction, while you are looking at the transaction in full detail on mempool.space.
Looking at the data you present, I guess that you made a payment of 0.00010000 BTC on 2022-03-05. The transaction paid a fee of 0.00001193 BTC. These two values sum up to 0.00011193 BTC leaving your Bitcoin Core wallet which matches the amount that you saw in your Bitcoin Core wallet.
The transaction also created a change output of ‎0.01208328 BTC to return the remainder of the inputs to your own wallet. This would mean that bc1qfjsm7jwdf3u7udnxhjtmpjvwuu2nvyjcq27pgj was another address of your wallet that the wallet created automatically for you. This change output was spent on 2023-06-06 in another transaction that created another output
bc1qp2all4l49u797expu7hrvldc2p8n86x22qhwqw  ‎0.01108328 BTC     

that is still unspent. I suspect that this output also belongs to your wallet.
Summing up the 1.15278884 BTC in your address 39L1wGdaPemy8vgQdz7CNU3QBDXthurLb7, and the 0.01108328 BTC from this change output results exactly in 1.16387212 BTC.
It looks like your wallet is fine, you just have another transaction output that was associated with an address that you were not tracking manually.
